# NavigationItem not showing on iPhone 5S/5C size

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have the following snippet to add a "next" button to the top right of my nav bar.

```
let next = UIButton()
next.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
next.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextButtonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: next)
```

This is showing fine on regular size phone, but NOT on my 5C... I can't figure out why.. I put a breakpoint where the right bar button item is set and it is NOT nil.. Help!

Comment: Why are you creating a `UIButton` instead of a normal `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: I wanted to have a custom text.. Didn't know how to do it without a UIButton

Comment: Nvm I figured how to set a title to the `UIBarButtonItem` and looks like it's working.. Still curious as to why it works on bigger phone sizes but not on 5C/5S though

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

1. let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: , style: , target: , action: )
2. Add the button to the navigationController

super easy